# PSU for server motherboard

Tags: power-supply

I have a H8QGL-IF+ server motherboard. And for it i need three 8 pin EPS connectors for CPU since this mobo has 4 cpus support. I bough 1000w PSU from he quiet ( DARK POWER 1000W P8 ) and it has only 1 slot to plug in EPS cable. Which adapters can i use or how can i get three 8 PIN EPS cables from this PSU? Also it has some odd 12 pin PCIE connectors, can i use those?

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image2]

.

Comment: Considering the investment here (server motherboard, potentially 4 x CPU, potentially lots of RAM) I am surprised you're willing to use a consumer-grade (and incompatible at that) PSU.

Comment: I searched the forums and everything and nobody using quad opteron motherboards didnt use any supermicro PSU. They all used AX1200, this bequiet or other PSU with adapters if needed.

Comment: Fair enough, in the end as long as the power is good you'll be good.  Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the motherboard manual](http://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/SR56x0/MNL-H8QGL-(6)(i)F+.pdf):

> The H8QGL-6/iF+ serverboard requires the use of proprietary power supplies.

You are trying to use an standard ATX PSU with a server board that requires a proprietary power supply (ATX + 3x 12v AUX).  So the "official" way to deal with this is get a properly-compatible PSU from SuperMicro.

If you want to hack it in, here's the pinout for the 12V connectors, which I believe will be the same as your single "P8" connector:

[image: AUX Poinout]

If so, you'll need to either bust out the soldering iron and parallel 2 more of these off the existing one (and hope the P8 rail can handle it), or find a couple 12V Molex -> P8 adapters such as [this one](http://www.newegg.ca/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812887002):

[image: Molex To P8]

Comment: Can you point me to a supermicro PSU?

Comment: You'll have to talk with a local SuperMicro reseller, or SuperMicro directly (who can point you to local a reseller). My guess is though, that you can't just buy a compatible PSU, as they probably (only) come as part of a chassis -- but you never know until you ask.  http://www.supermicro.com/wheretobuy